# how to display mysql result to label or text?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Need to display the result of a mysql string to a label or textbox.

Only got a code to embed the results to a listview:

```
Sub fillListview()
    Try
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer"
        objCmd = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSQL, objConn)
        objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader

        While (objDR.Read())
            With ListView1.Items.Add(objDR("Cust_Id"))
                .subitems.add(objDR("Cust_Name"))
                .subitems.add(objDR("Cust_Age"))
                .subitems.add(objDR("Items"))
                .subitems.add(objDR("Price_Accumulated"))
                .subitems.add(objDR("Date"))
                .subitems.add(objDR("Time"))
            End With
        End While

        objCmd.Dispose()
        objDR.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Also i've already put strsql, objCmd etc. as a variable in a module so no need for it to be a DIM

(BTW I don't know why only the While is recognized as a code :|)

Comment: thnx for editing it :D

Answer (score 0):

try this format:

```
 Sub fillListview()
Try
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer"
    objCmd = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSQL, objConn)
    objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader

    While (objDR.Read())
           textBox.Text=objDR("Cust_Id").toString()
    End While

    objCmd.Dispose()
    objDR.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

End Sub

place this inside the while statement.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to use that and if it works I'll accept the answer :D

Comment: got an error saying object "reference not to set an instance of an object"

Also btw here's the code I'm using if you see any mistakes please correct them, (I'm a noob :p)

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        strSQL = "SELECT Cust_Name FROM customer WHERE Cust_Name='Minato Arisato' LIMIT 1"

        objCmd = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSQL, objConn)
        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Label1.Text = objDR("Cust_Name").ToString()
        objCmd.Dispose()
    End Sub

Comment: i edited my answer. you removed the executeReader that's why u'r getting that error